# Moving data between TSQL servers without backup or BCP

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, database-migration

I have a very large database with near 21 million rows in various tables.  It took months to get it filled out, and I've been told that I now have to move it.

The server it is on right now, I have VPN access and can work with the HDD at-will.  It runs Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

The server I need to transfer it to is one of those SQL-only servers that do not allow you to VPN or access the HDD in any way.  It does have an FTP site that I can upload .bak files to, and then a way through their interface to restore .bak files to a database; however this will not work since the version of Microsoft SQL Server on this server is 2012.  It is not backwards compatible.

Since I do not have access to the HDD I have also ruled out using bulk file commands (BCP).  I may be able to perform link server operations if I open the right ports, but I am afraid it will take a week to transfer this way.

Does anyone know of any other options I can try here?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can restore the DB locally to your environment as a 2014 DB. Then you can ETL the data (SQL import/export utility, DDL/DML scripts) to a 2012 DB instance. Then back it up natively (2012) and upload the BAK to your provider and restore it.  This assumes you're not using functionality in 2014 that is not available in 2012.

Comment: I actually just had the same idea.  Going to take a while to try it.